# Error 9 al implementar RecognitionListener en Android

Tags: android, procesamiento-de-texto

Estoy usando la interfaz de reconocimiento en mi aplicación para convertir la voz en texto.
Actualmente intento implementar **RecognitionListener** en Android y recibo el error 9 al empezar la escucha de voz en mi aplicación.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private TextView mText;
private SpeechRecognizer sr;
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());
}

class listener implements RecognitionListener {
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
    }
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
    }
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
    }
    public void onError(int error) {
        Log.d(TAG, "error " + error);
        mText.setText("error " + error);
    }
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        String str = new String();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
        ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
            str += data.get(i);
        }
        mText.setText("results: " + String.valueOf(data.size()));
    }
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
    }
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "voice.recognition.test");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
        sr.startListening(intent);
       }
   }
 }
```

Adicionalmente quisiera lograr este efecto en tiempo real.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxHdMJXrMP2HRk80aVBtZHIxaDA

he buscado información al respecto y creo que tengo que trabajar dentro del método onPartialResults pero no logro implementarlo correctamente.
¿Hay alguna forma de detectar una palabra a la vez y mostrarla una por una?

Muchas gracias.